# ReactJS checkbox multiple selected not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having hardtime by fixing this component. I got error when I am selecting multiple item with checkbox. But in my other component, there is no error, same code. Please check my code below, thank you guys.

```
export default class TreeNode extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            collapsed: true,
            checked: []
        }
    }

    onClick(){
        this.setState({
            collapsed : !this.state.collapsed
        });
    }    

    checkBoxHandle(id,e){
        if (e.target.checked){
            let {checked} = this.state
            checked.push(id)
            this.setState({checked :checked })
        } else{
            //If checkbox uncheck = remove in the list
            let {checked} = this.state
            const getIndex = checked.indexOf(id)
            checked.splice(getIndex,1)
            this.setState({checked : checked})
        }
    }

    render(){

        let subtree = null;
        if (this.props.data.children){
            subtree = this.props.data.children.map(function(child){
                return <TreeNode  key= {child.id} data ={child} />;
            }.bind(this))
        }
        const temp_id = this.props.data.id
        var arrowClassName = 'tree-node-arrow';
        var containerClassName = 'tree-node-children'
        if (subtree){
            return (
                <div className="tree-node">       
                    <input type="checkbox" onClick ={this.checkBoxHandle.bind(this,this.props.data.id)}/>
                    <a data-id={this.props.data.id}>
                        {this.props.data.description}
                    </a>

                    <div className={containerClassName}>
                        {subtree}
                    </div>
                </div>
              );
        }
        else {
            return (
                <div className="tree-node-leaf">
                   <input type="checkbox" onClick ={this.checkBoxHandle.bind(this,this.props.data.id)}/>
                    <a data-id={this.props.data.id}>
                        {this.props.data.description}
                    </a>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I am updating the checked state everytime there is checked item, and I am removing if the user unchecked the checkbox.

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: Don't have error but only, wrong output. It is not updating the checked array in my state. 
Check this picture: https://imgur.com/5M6crUg

Answer (score 0):

It's because you use the mutable methods for `checked` like `push` and `splice` while a component's state is immutable. So do it in an immutable way with rest operator and `filter` method like this:

```
class Checkboxes extends React.Component {
  state = {
    checked: []
  };

  onChange = (e) => {
    const { checked } = this.state;
    const { id } = e.target;
    if (checked.indexOf(id) === -1) {
      this.setState({
        checked: [...checked, id]
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({ checked: checked.filter(checkedId => checkedId !== id) });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { checked } = this.state;
    console.log(`CHECKED: ${checked}`);
    return (
      <div className="checkboxes">
        <label htmlFor="checkbox1">Checkbox 1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.onChange} id="1" checked={checked.indexOf("1") !== -1} />
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="checkbox2">Checkbox 2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.onChange} id="2" checked={checked.indexOf("2") !== -1} />
        <br />
        <label htmlFor="checkbox3">Checkbox 3</label>
        <input type="checkbox" onChange={this.onChange} id="3" checked={checked.indexOf("3") !== -1} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/teimurjan/pen/NzoZYK) is the working Codepen example.

Comment: My wrong is my checkbox onchange and changing state should be in parent component. I got it now. Thank you for the answer

Comment: It's not a good solution. It's working in a parent because your child component is updated every time when it gets the new props. When you use the state your component is not rendered again as your array remains the same(elements are different but the array object has the same pointer). If you try to optimize your app using React.PureComponent you will receive the same mistakes even when onChange and state are in parent because PureComponent compares the previous and the next props like state does. So I advise you to change the method of your state's mutation.